# Preserve HTML tables with CSS in preparation for being converted to PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, html-table, pdf-generation

I'm using a proprietary 3rd party reporting tool that has a feature which will convert the HTML version of the report and convert it to a PDF. I have no direct control over how the PDF conversion is done. However, I can control the CSS of the HTML which indirectly affects the generated PDF. It really only has trouble with tables. I've seen similar problems with other pdf-converter tools. Things like:

- multiple header rows for a single table don't get repeated on each page of the PDF.
- page breaking in the middle of row cells
- page breaking in between the table caption and the table itself.

What are good best practices for applying CSS styling to HTML tables so that it produces the best results when the HTML is converted to a PDF?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to style your page, esp. the table, for the print media i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" ...` first. That would at least save you some time from calling the 3rd party reporting tool.

I'd also check whether the available width of the PDF page is less than your (targeted) page width. It sounds like related to your issues (#2 and #3 in your list).

Answer (score 0):

## 1 use display: table-header-group; in ur css

## 2 & #3 you can use page breaks: page-break-before:always, page-break-after:always and page-break-inside:avoid in ur css